# Suggestions for Looping in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

There is an an array of objects. I want to put that in a loop to find whether the checked is true or false.. if it is true then i wanna concatinate with the value of each array. Any suggestions please

```
plugin:[ 
{checked :true,value:'link', name:'link', id:'linkId'}, 
 {checked  :true,value:'plug', name:'plug', id:'plugId'}, 
 {checked :true, value:'switch', name:'switch', id:'switchId'}, 
]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this: "i wanna concatinate with the value of each array".

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
const plugin = [ 
    {checked :true,value:'link', name:'link', id:'linkId'}, 
    {checked  :true,value:'plug', name:'plug', id:'plugId'}, 
    {checked :true, value:'switch', name:'switch', id:'switchId'}, 
];

render() {
    return (
        <div> 
        { plugin.map(el => {
            return el.checked ? el.value : null ;
        }) } 
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

Comment: Need to fix your braces.

Comment: @RickJolly, where ?

Comment: `return { ...`. I'd just do `return plugin.map(...`. But can React `render` return an array of strings? Or is this not supposed to be a react render?

Comment: @RickJolly, Nice catch , need to put it within div

Comment: Need a curly brace right before the last `div` and either a paren after return `return (...`, or move the first div up to the return `return <div>...`. Nitpicking, but could also shorten the map: `{ plugin.map(el => el.checked ? el.value : null) }``